# EF Core - Don't know how to config 1 - N in same entity 2 times

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, ef-fluent-api

The context is : A Student can make appointments to Mentor and Mentor can have many appointments. Mentor may be student or lecturer.
I don't separate Student and Mentor but merge them into one entities User

```
public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Avatar { get; set; }
    public string MeetUrl { get; set; }
    public bool? IsMentor { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Appointment
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string StudentId { get; set; }
    public User Student { get; set; }

    public string MentorId { get; set; }
    //public User Mentor { get; set; }

    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }

}
```

I don't know how to config the relation of these entities with fluent-api to fit with the context.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
      base.OnModelCreating(builder);

      builder.Entity<Appointment>()
          .HasOne<User>(a => a.Student)
          .WithMany(st => st.Appointments)
          .HasForeignKey(st => st.StudentId);


      builder.Entity<Appointment>()
          .HasOne<User>(a => a.Mentor)
          .WithMany(m => m.Appointments)
          .HasForeignKey(a => a.MentorId);
}
```

Should I separate User into 2 entities Student, Mentor?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do here with fluent syntax is set up "navigation properties".

Consider the following piece your code:

```
 builder.Entity<Appointment>()
      .HasOne<User>(a => a.Student)
      .WithMany(st => st.Appointments)
      .HasForeignKey(st => st.StudentId);
```

Here you are saying Appointments and User have a one-to-many relation where `StudentId` is your FK and `Student` represents the **one** User item this relation is linked to. You are also saying `Appointments` represents that **many** appointments that are linked to the `User` record the via the FK `StudentId`.

In other words, in this piece of code, you have specified that `Appointments` represents all the appointments of the current `User` as a student and **not** as a mentor. However, in the next fluent syntax, you are similarly trying to set the same property `Appointments` to represent the list of appointments that the current user has as a mentor.

You can't have the same property for both these use cases. You would need two properties in your `User` table like `AppointmentsAsStudent` and `AppointmentsAsMentor`.

Comment: Maybe you should show how this many-to-many relationship (which it is) should be configured.

Comment: Thanks, may be I need seperate the User into 2 entities Student and Mentor. Thanks you!

Comment: @GertArnold Yes, OPs explanation does sound like a many-to-many, but his models seem like he is going for a 1 to many